# Conditional operations between factor level pairs

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

I have a dataframe (`df1`) that contains `Start` times and `End` times for observations of different `ID`s:

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:4, Start = c("2021-05-12 13:22:00", "2021-05-12 13:25:00", "2021-05-12 13:30:00", "2021-05-12 13:42:00"), 
End = c("2021-05-13 8:15:00", "2021-05-13 8:17:00", "2021-05-13 8:19:00", "2021-05-13 8:12:00")), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

I want to create a new dataframe that shows the latest `Start` time and the earliest `End` time for each possible pairwise comparison between the levels of`ID`.

I was able to accomplish this by making a duplicate column of `ID` called `ID2`, using `dplyr::expand` to expand them, and saving that in an object called `Pairs`:

```
library(dplyr)
df$ID2 <- df$ID
Pairs <- 
  df%>%
  expand(ID, ID2)
```

Making two new objects `a` and `b` that store the `Start` and `End` times for each comparison separately, and then combining them into `df2`:

```
a <- left_join(df, Pairs, by = 'ID')%>%
  rename(StartID1 = Start, EndID1 = End, ID2 = ID2.y)%>%
  select(-ID2.x)
b <- left_join(Pairs, df, by = "ID2")%>%
  rename(StartID2 = Start, EndID2 = End)%>%
  select(ID2, StartID2, EndID2)
df2 <- cbind(a,b)
df2 <- df2[,-4]
```

and finally using `dplyr::if_else` to find the `LatestStart` time and the `EarliestEnd` time for each of the comparisons:

```
df2 <- 
  df2%>%
  mutate(LatestStart = if_else(StartID1 > StartID2, StartID1, StartID2),
         EarliestEnd = if_else(EndID1 > EndID2, EndID2, EndID1))
```

This seems like such a simple task to perform, is there a more concise way to achieve this from `df1` without creating all of these extra objects?

Answer (score 0):

For such computations usually `outer` comes handy:

```
df %>%
  mutate(across(c("Start", "End"), lubridate::ymd_hms)) %>%
  {
    data.frame(
      ID1 = rep(.$ID, each = nrow(.)),
      ID2 = rep(.$ID, nrow(.)),
      LatestStart = outer(.$Start, .$Start, pmax),
      LatestEnd = outer(.$End, .$End, pmin)
    )
  }
```

Comment: when I run this code, I get `Error in `[.default`(xj, i, , drop = FALSE) : subscript out of bounds`